# substring from one char to the other

Tags: java, database, string, substring

Hi there lovely people of StackOverFlow.

It just so happend to be that i need help regarding a what i would guess is a rather easy problem to solve in java.

I have a document of 40 000 lines of text that lookes like this.

```
<syn level="3.3"><w1>wordOne</w1><w2>WordTwo</w2></syn>
<syn level="4.3"><w1>WordThree</w1><w2>WordFour</w2></syn>
<syn level="3.3"><w1>wordFive</w1><w2>WordSix</w2></syn>
```

and so on an so on. What i want to be able to do is to take out the leftside words and put them all into an array and the same goes for the rightside.

I came up with a solution that looked something like this.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size();i++){

        int iEnd = lines.get(i).indexOf('€');

        firstWord.add(lines.get(i).substring(21, iEnd));
    }

   <syn level="3.3"><w1>wordOne€</w1><w2>WordTwo</w2></syn>
```

However this would force me to sit down and write 80 000 '€' and it just feels like there has to be a better way of doing it.

Comment: Read on [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: If you got a document containing XML you might want to consider to use an XML parser. RegExp are as mighty as dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to manually add '€' to mark the end of the word? You already know that the word ends with `</w1>`

So you can write something like this

```
int iEnd = lines.get(i).indexOf("</w1>");
```

And leave the rest of the code as it is and it should be fine.

Comment: Oh so that works? though it only took char as a parameter

Comment: It accepts both. You can check what parameters it accepts from this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, and search for indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a regular expression like this:

```
<w1>(\w+)<\/w1><w2>(\w+)<\/w2>
```

First create a `Pattern`

```
Pattern c = Pattern.compile("<w1>(\\w+)<\\/w1><w2>(\\w+)<\\/w2>");
```

Then for each line run a matcher

```
Matcher m = c.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1) );
  System.out.println(m.group(2) );
}
```